# How to get a value of a selected item in combo box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combo box called combo0 that has been populated with a query. It has three columns (ID, Int-name and sat name) column 1 is bounded. I want to store the id column so I can use it latter on. 
I have tried

```
dim object Id as integer
object id = combo0.value
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: `Dim object Id As Integer` ? Try  `Dim ID As Integer`..

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. But I figured it out. I was debugging before I moved on to makes sure I extracted the value correctly. But it would stop debugging when it got to that line but it was storing the value. I know a very stupid mistake. Cheers to All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a Duplicate but

Try,

```
objectId=combo0.column(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If [ID] is the bound column then use Object ID = me.combo0.column(0).  Simply using Object ID = me.combo0.value should also work.  You may consider storing the value as a global variable.